# Solving second order ODE using Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$2tx''+(1+t)x'+x=0$
where $t$ is the independent variable

im stuck at:

$2\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_n t^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nt^{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nt^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nt^n=0$

I know that I have to somehowe re-index the sums so they start at the same n and have the t to the same power so I can write it as a one sum and factor the $t^n$ out.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

1)$2\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)a_nt^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+1)na_{n+1}t^n$

2)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n-1}=a_{1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}t^{n}$

3)$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nt^{n}$

4)$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nt^n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nt^n$, so:

$a_0+a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[(n+1)na_{n+1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_n+a_n]t^n$

You have:

$a_1+a_0=0$

$(n+1)na_{n+1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}+na_n+a_n=0$ for $n \geq 1$